# Animation on position working slow on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create html page where a pen will move as 
user types in textarea. To create animation as though its writing I am 
moving the pen up and down. The animation works fine in chrome but its lagging in IE.
Please suggest me on how to improve the speed of animation and make it write as user types.
Though IE8 is not as good as chrome or any other browsers, the code should work in IE8+ as per the requirement, please help

```
  var contentHeight = $("#Typing").textareaHelper('height');
            $("#Typing").height(contentHeight);
            localleft = $("#Typing").textareaHelper('caretPos').left + 280;
            localtop = $("#Typing").textareaHelper('caretPos').top;

            $('#Feather').animate({ left: (($("#Typing").textareaHelper('caretPos').left) + 270) },1,animation2);
            $('#Feather').animate({ top: (($("#Typing").textareaHelper('caretPos').top) - 8) }, 1);
            $('#Feather').animate({ left: (($("#Typing").textareaHelper('caretPos').left) + 280) }, 1);
            $('#Feather').animate({ top: $("#Typing").textareaHelper('caretPos').top }, 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the first thing I'd optimize is all the times you are searching the DOM.  Every time you do this.

```
$("#Typing")
```

You are searching the page for that element.  Better to load it once and then manipulate it.

```
var $typing = $("#Typing");
// do your animations with $typing.animate();
```

It may not solve the whole problem, but it's a start.

Edit: Do the same for $("#Feather")